# How to get data of 2 tables with groupBy and orderBy id & get last inserted data

Tags: eloquent, laravel-9

I'm trying to get the data from 2 different tables by using join method. I have done creating a Eloquent procedure to achieve that which is working perfectly with `orderBy()` method as well.

Now I just wanted to group the data based on a column with the same Eloquent methods is not returning me the latest/last inserted data.

My query for your reference below,

```
$def_reminders = Invoice::from('invoices AS inv')
->join('reminders_calendar AS remcal', 'remcal.invoice_id', '=', 'inv.id')
->where([
    'inv.user_id' => 1,
    'inv.is_deleted' => '0',
])
->where('inv.reminder_status', '!=', 'Enabled')
->whereDate('remcal.date_when', '2024-01-03')
->whereIn('remcal.reminder_type', ['InProgress', 'Waiting'])
// ->whereRaw('remcal.id = (select max(`id`) from reminders_calendar)')
->selectRaw('MAX(remcal.id) as remcal_id, remcal.invoice_id AS remcal_invoice_id, remcal.*, inv.*')
->groupBy('remcal.invoice_id')
->orderBy('remcal.id', 'desc')
->get();
```

Whenever I commented the `groupBy('remcal.invoice_id')` method returns me all data with order of latest/ last data to previous data correctly.

I'm bit confused to get the data from 2 tables when with the `groupBy()` and `orderBy()` method in the join query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a solution to make it work. When am use groupBy, it groups the rows that have the same values in specified columns into aggregated data. In my case, it’s grouping by `remcal.invoice_id`. And, when I use `orderBy('remcal.id', 'desc')`, it’s trying to order by the id of remcal in descending order. But because of the groupBy, it might not be the latest `id` that gets selected in the group, hence am not getting the latest inserted data.

My working code as follows,

```
$sub = DB::table('reminders_calendar')
->select('invoice_id', DB::raw('MAX(id) as max_id'))
->groupBy('invoice_id');

$def_reminders = DB::table('invoices AS inv')
->joinSub($sub, 'max_remcal', function ($join) {
    $join->on('inv.id', '=', 'max_remcal.invoice_id');
})
->join('reminders_calendar AS remcal', function ($join) {
    $join->on('inv.id', '=', 'remcal.invoice_id')
         ->on('remcal.id', '=', 'max_remcal.max_id');
})
->where([
    'inv.user_id' => 1,
    'inv.is_deleted' => '0',
])
->where('inv.reminder_status', '!=', 'Enabled')
->whereDate('remcal.date_when', '2024-01-03')
->whereIn('remcal.reminder_type', ['InProgress', 'Waiting'])
->select('remcal.*', 'inv.*')
->orderBy('remcal.id', 'desc')
->get();
```